# AVPlayer override video controls

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I need to be notified when a control button (on a video) is pressed. For example if I tap on the "pause" or on "full scren" button I need to implement some logic. Can I override methods of `AVPlayerViewController`? I found `AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate` but I can't find any methods to override.

I also tried to add an observer to the AVPlayer

```
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
```

and I used:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String,
ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [String : AnyObject],
context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
...
}
```

but I get a notification only when the video is played: this method isn't called if I tap on a control button.

Thanks

Comment: How to detect touch when user pressed forward/backward button? Or can we hide them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keypaths are different, for swift, to check play/pause after clicked:

```
  player .addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
```

and in

```
observeValueForKeyPath
```

check like this

```
if ((change!["new"] as! Int) == 1)
```

^ this returns if video played or paused for true/false cases

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayer emit an NSNotification when pause is pressed. `AVPlayerDidPauseNotification` (or something like that). You can register a listener in the `NSNotificationCenter` for this notification.